# Find returns object on child element

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to find all the fruit in my database where the colour is not red however when I run the find command below it returns [object]. What am I doing wrong

database: `mongoDB`

```
"fruit": {
    "color": [
      "red"
    ]
  }
```

Path: `server.js`

```
 var fruit = fruit.find({
                    "fruit.color": { $nin: [ red ] },
                  }).fetch();
```

If I console log on the server it retuns the following.

```
console.log(fruit);

{ color: [Object] } } ]
```

Comment: noticed you are using the same variable name for the collection and the result.

Comment: try to check what is that object.. console.log(fruit.color)

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(fruit)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys it helped me find a solution. The problem I had was `[ ]` in my $nin query. When I removed that it worked. To be honest I have no idea why.  `var fruit = fruit.find({
                    "fruit.color": { $nin:  red  },
                  }).fetch();`

Answer (score 1):

Your find returns an array of objects, that's why you get the [object] result. You have to iterate the result. Like:

```
var fruits = fruit.find({
                    "fruit.color": { $nin: [ red ] },
                  }).fetch();

fruits.forEach(function (afruit) {
            console.log(afruit.color);
        });
```